# need result of two table sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have a two sql server tables that contains data like this

Table a

```
catId    |    catname          | Isdeleted
-------------------------------------------------

1               ABC               0
2               DEF               0
3               GHI               0
```

and another table is

Table B

```
id    |     Name    |    Name1      | Catid  
--------------------------------------------------
1           abc           aaaa           1 
2           def           bbbb           1 
3           ghi           gggg           2 
4           jkl           jjjj           2 
5           xyz           xxxxx          3
```

Now I want result in this format

> catname from table a and all the fields from table b according to
>   catid of table a and   catname should be distinct.

Please help me

Comment: You need to decide how you want it to appear, then.  It's a lot more complicated to have a variable number of fields, which is what you are asking for (unless there is a maximum number of records per `CatId` in table b).

Answer (score 1):

Write your query like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.catname, b.* FROM a INNER JOIN b 
ON a.catid = b.catid WHERE catid = [catid]
```

If you have multiple records in table b for each catid or catname, you will see multiple records with same catname in result. there is no other choice unless catname be unique in both tables a and b.

Comment: but it displaying the duplicate catname and i need only distinct catnamae and all the records according to that catname

Comment: If you have multiple records in table b for each catid or catname, you will see multiple records with same catname in result. there is no other choice unless catname be unique in both tables a and b.

Comment: @anil what you are asking for is to denormalize the data.  Any particular reason for that?  Most of the time, that's a bad idea.